# How to set read-only columns in Hibernate?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, orm, relational-database

I don't know how to force read-only columns in Hibernate.

I would like to set idgroup as read only column. Even if I set `insertable=false` and `updatable=false`, in the hibernate SQL I can read:

```
Hibernate: insert into groups (description, name, account_idaccount, idgroup) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

but I would like to obtain:

```
insert into groups (description, name, account_idaccount) values (?, ?, ?)
```

Here are my classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "groups")
public class Group implements java.io.Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -2948610975819234753L;
private GroupId id;
private Account account;
private String name;
private String description;

@EmbeddedId
@AttributeOverrides({@AttributeOverride(name = "idgroup", column = @Column(name = "idgroup", insertable = false)),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "accountIdaccount", column = @Column(name = "account_idaccount", nullable = false))})
public GroupId getId() {
    return id;
}

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "account_idaccount", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
public Account getAccount() {
    return account;
}

@Column(name = "description", length = 512)
public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}


@Column(name = "name", nullable = false, length = 128)
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
..
}
```

```
@Embeddable
public class GroupId implements java.io.Serializable {

private int idgroup;
private int accountIdaccount;

@Column(name = "idgroup", insertable= false, updatable= false)
public int getIdgroup() {
    return this.idgroup;
}


@Column(name = "account_idaccount", nullable = false)
public int getAccountIdaccount() {
    return this.accountIdaccount;
}
..
}
```

I would like to have a read only column for idgroup because I can exploit the id auto-generation of the DBMS, I do not want to use the key auto-generation in Hibernate because it is not cluster-safe.

Comment: have a look at http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en-US/html/readonly.html  and http://ndpsoftware.com/HibernateMappingCheatSheet.html - they may give you hints

Comment: thanks Rachel, but the first link refers to read only entities, and I don't see the second useful to my case

Comment: ah well. thought you could set the optimistic lock to true

Comment: Is it good for you if hibernate instead of not trying to persist your readonly value just persist always the same what he collected when getting entity from dbms?

Comment: the problem is when I create an instance from Java and I want to save it in the database, even if I don't initialize the idgroup, hibernate writes 0 because it is the default value for int.

Comment: This wasn't tagged with JPA, but my guess is you will need to specify a SequenceGenerator to get it to use your database's sequencing, otherwise it will not be usable in relationships etc.  You are also overriding your column to only be insertable=false - someone else suggested it be marked both insertable+updatable=false

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The solution is using wrapper classes, such as `Integer`, **not primitive** types like `int`.
When Hibernate will get a null pointer it will delegate the generation of the id to the DBMS.

Answer (score 15):

I think you can mark an `@Column` annotation as `updatable=false`

Comment: already done, if you read the code above in GroupId.getIdgroup()

Answer (score 7):

Easy:

```java
@Column(insertable = false, updatable = false)
```

Comment: consider adding more information as to how this solve's the problem for OP

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this by using 2 DAO objects. I know it may not be preferred, but I didn't see another way around it. Setting the field to `insertable=false` and `updatable=false` do not remove the columns from the insert SQL so Postgres will not invoke the `default` action to populate those column values.

```
   // GroupWrite

   @Entity
   @Table(name = "group")
   public class GroupWrite {

      @Id
      @Column(name = "account")
      private Account account;

      @Column(name = "name")
      private String name;

      @Column(name = "description")
      private String description;


      /* Getters and Setters */
  }
```

--

```
   // GroupRead

   @Entity
   @Table(name = "group")
   public class GroupRead {

      @EmbeddedId
      @Column(name = "id")
      private GroupId id;

      @Column(name = "account")
      private Account account;

      @Column(name = "name")
      private String name;

      @Column(name = "description")
      private String description;


      /* Getters and Setters */
  }
```

Then you need to use the `GroupRead` when using `select` queries and `GroupWrite` when doing `insert` or `update` queries.

If you want to use attributes from both in a common way you can implement an interface that describes the overlapping fields.

```
   public interface Group {

        Account getAccount();

        void setAccount(Account account);
   }

   public class GroupWrite implements Group {...}

   public class GroupRead implements Group {...}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -3):

@ReadOnlyProperty annotation will help you in this case.

Comment: It's always useful to add an explanation on *how* would things help.

Comment: It didn't help me. At least the one I found, which was org.springframework.data.annotation.ReadOnlyProperty. I didn't find a Hibernate property by that name.